# can't remove borders from table in lotus notes 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a html signature, and use lotus notes 8.5, after inserting html file for signature(File->Prefernces->Mail->Signature Tab as Rich text and them import html file) my table has style `border:0` but after it loses that style and in gmail borders are displayed and it's so ugly, want to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the style you have specified for the table inline? From memory gmail prefers it this way, ie:

```
<td style="border:0">
```

rather than

```
<style>
td { border:0 }
</style>
```

worth a try.

Nick